# $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $1$ for any $x\in [0,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Give an example of random variables $X_n$ with densities $f_n$ so that $X_n\Rightarrow $ a uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ but $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $1$ for any $x\in [0,1]$.

I tried a lot of examples, but none of are working. I might missing some easy example. Thanks for any help.

I tried $x^{(1+1/n)}$, $x(1-1/n)^x$ etc.

$\Rightarrow$ means weak convergence.

Comment: What kind of convergence does "$\Rightarrow$" denote?

Comment: Try a "sliding window": $f_n$ is the density of a uniform distribution over $(0,1)\setminus S_n$, for a set $S_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert S_n\rvert = 0$ but every fixed $x$ belongs to infinitely many $S_n$. (E.g., $S_n$ "slides" around $(0,1)$)

Comment: @angryavian $\Rightarrow$ means weak convergence.

Comment: What about just taking $f_n(x) = 1+\frac1n$ on $(\frac1{n+1},1)$ and $0$ elsewhere? That is, $X_n$ is uniform on $(\frac1{n+1},1)$. Oh, never mind, I guess this converges to $1$ everywhere.